# Switching language without restarting?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, language-support

I'm learning a new language and I'd like to be able to switch my system language to better immerse myself.

I've installed the new language pack, but I noticed Gnome requires you to logout and restart the window manager in order to show the new language.

Since I always have a lot of workspaces and windows open, I really don't want to logout every time I switch a language.

Is this just a limitation of Gnome or is this some way to change language without restarting? Is there a desktop that doesn't require restarting to switch language?

Comment: what does `killall gnome-shell` do after you changed language? it should reload the desktop but I am not sure if that also changes language.

Comment: I can switch keyboard input language without logout and login, but I am almost sure you have to restart gnome if you change the system language.